# A tree that is both memory efficient and disk-space efficient?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, avl-tree, b-tree

I recently started reading about Data Structures in detail. I came across trees. AVL trees are designed taking fast memory access into consideration and B trees are designed taking efficient disk storage into consideration. Suppose I want to design a tree which is both memory efficient and disk storage efficient, what tree should I use? Is there any way I can combine AVL tree and B Tree? Is there any other tree that can do both? Is this fundamentally possible in a real-world scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to design a tree which is both memory efficient and disk storage efficient (...) Is there any way I can combine AVL tree and B Tree?

Short answer is no, there isn't, unless you make a breakthrough discovery in the field of data structures. Both of them were designed with specific optimization requirements in mind, you can't have the best of both worlds.

There's a concept in computing called [Space–time tradeoff](http://localhost:4000/2019/08/data-structures-complexity-reference) which can be extended to other types of tradeoffs, like the one you're interested in. You can think of it like this: to improve a property of an already optimized algorithm you will have to worsen another (unless you discover some new approach no one thought before).

I suggest you take a look at the available implementations of optimized [Binary Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Binary_trees) and start with the one that best fits your needs.